# Order Of META tags and Search Engine Ranking?

Tags: seo

If I place the META description tag after the META keywords tag, will that impact one's ranking in a search engine?

Answer (score 3):

No. Not only does the order not matter but neither one affect your search engine rankings anyway.

Comment: Right. The only thing to add - put a meaningful `description` because sometimes a search engine may use your description metatag as the description of your page that it displays in search results.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, as long as you have all the required ones there. Things like dublin core seem to be more of a good thing to include now, however there is a thread about this very subject here: [SO thread on subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572471/in-head-which-comes-first-meta-or-title)

Answer (score 0):

The placement makes no difference.  The current thinking on META Descriptions and Keywords is that they no longer carry much weight in the total equation that determines the SERP rankings.  Even so, I meticulously keep them appropriate for each of my pages.  The most important consideration is that the META Description very frequently used on the SERP, so make sure that it is well written balancing SEO and your marketing angle.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags are good to have for informational purposes, but don't carry much SEO weight in and of themselves.

You'd be better off keeping a regular blog, if you're looking for SERP improvements.