# HTML5: Meta charset before title?

Tags: html

I often see this:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Title</title>
...
</head>
```

Is it important to put the chartset definition BEFORE the the title tag?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [In <head>, which comes first: <meta> or <title>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572471/in-head-which-comes-first-meta-or-title)

Answer (score 9):

yes it is, see https://code.google.com/p/doctype-mirror/wiki/MetaCharsetAttribute

> In order for all browsers to recognize a `<meta charset>` declaration,
>   it must be
>
> - Within the `<head>` element,
> - Before any elements that contain text, such as the `<title>` element, AND
> - Within the first 512 bytes of your document, including DOCTYPE and whitespace