# What is the significance of these two metadata elements in <head>

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have some redundant metadata tags in my `<head>` that I'm not sure I need, nor do I know if they are in the right order. I am using the gem "meta-tags"

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<%= display_meta_tags %>
```

Do I need both `meta_tags` elements and is where they're located okay/best-practice?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346917/why-use-x-ua-compatible-ie-edge-anymore

Comment: I am guessing you are referring to `csrf_meta_tags` and `display_meta_tags`. They are completely different: `csrf_meta_tags` is a Rails helper to handle request forgery and `display_meta_tags` is a meta-tags gem helper to display SEO tags. Location is fine for both (the order of meta tags in `head` doesn't really matter)

Comment: @AbM Thanks, This is pretty interesting. I never knew they were completely different! Should I remove this question, or would you like to leave an official answer?

Comment: @AbM Quick note - the `charset` meta tag should be the very first meta tag in the head - the order does matter at least for that one tag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682496/html5-meta-charset-before-title

Comment: Thanks @MaximillianLaumeister, I added your comment in the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are referring to `csrf_meta_tags` and `display_meta_tags`. They are completely different:

- [`csrf_meta_tags`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/CsrfHelper.html) is a Rails helper to handle request forgery.
- [`display_meta_tags`](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/meta-tags/1.2.1/MetaTags%2FViewHelper:display_meta_tags) is a meta-tags gem helper to display SEO tags.

Location is fine for both. The order of meta tags in head doesn't really matter, except for the `charset` meta tag that [should be in the first position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682496/html5-meta-charset-before-title)